# NSView drawRect: being erased

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsview, drawrect

For some strange reason parts of my NSView are being erased when another view comes in contact with it.  I imagine this is some sort of layer issue, would I be correct in believing that?  My first thought was to just constantly redraw the NSView with `[self setNeedsDisplay:YES]` but that doesn't exactly work (only sometimes), and it makes the animations stutter.

Here are some images to clarify...
[image]
[image]
[image]

Any clue how I can solve this issue?  Thanks!

EDIT: Fixed, see below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[myView setWantsLayer:YES]` on all necessary NSView's to force proper layer based drawing.  Hope this helps someone!

[image]